# How many integer solutions $n$ there are for which $n^3-3\;$ is divisible by $n-3$?

Tags: combinatorics, divisibility, integers

> How many integer solutions $n$ there are for which $n^3-3\;$ is divisible by $n-3$?

WolframAlpha calculated $16$ integer solutions, but I don't know how did it get the solution.

I tried to solve for $\frac{n^3-3}{n-3}=c$ where $c$ is an integer, but I don't know how to solve equations for integer solutions.

Comment: Are you sure about correctnes of your question?

Comment: Equivalently, find the solutions of $m|((m+3)^3-3)$ or $m|(m^3+9m^2+27m+24)$ or $m|24$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{n^3-3}{n-3}=n^2+3n+9+\frac{24}{n-3}$$

$$24=2^3\times 3$$

Number of positive divisors of $24$ is $(3+1)\times (1+1)=8$

$n$ values are $27, 15, 11, 9, 7, 6, 5, 4$

Then $24$ has $8$ negative divisors.

$n$ values are $-21, -9, -5, --3, -1, 0, 1, 2$

There are $16$ different $n$ that makes the given  expression integer.